# Is it possible to design Dialogs within a Dialog, both created with ressource editor?

Tags: windows, winapi, dialog

Is it possible to create a dialog ressource with a resource editor and *then* put this dialog (possibly multiple times) into another dialog?

Here's some background. I need to create a C++ program (Windows). The user needs to input a set of similar data on a dialog. Say, for simplicity's sake, an element of this data-set consist of an edit control and a scrollbar. Since this combination (edit + scrollbar) needs to be put onto the dialog for each element for the data-set, I thought I could create a simple dialog with just one edit control and one scrollbar, and then put this dialog mutliple times onto its "parent" dialog.

So, is this possible at all. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is the notion of a UserControl in point-and-click designers.  Maybe a dialog can be banged into some short of shape like that, it certainly wasn't designed to be a child window.  Maybe the bigger question is why you're trying to do something that's so simple in, say, Winforms in a raw user32 C++ program.  That's 5 minutes vs a week of your life.  More if you try to do this with dialogs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.

In the dialog editor, set the "Control Parent" flag on the parent dialog. (This will ensure the tab key works to cycle through items in the child dialogs as if they were part of the parent dialog.)

Make sure the child dialog(s) have the "Child" flag set in the dialog editor. Visually, they'll look like dialogs without any border at all in the editor.

At runtime, create the child dialogs as children of the parent dialog using [CreateDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645434%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (or CreateDialogParam, etc.). When calling CreateDialog you specify the dialogproc for each window.

I often make the child dialog procs do little more than forward messages to the main window's dialog proc (calling it directly; not via SendMessage), but you have to be careful, obviously. You have to be especially careful if you are creating multiple copies of the same dialog in a single parent, since obviously the control IDs within that dialog will all be the same and you need to differentiate them (perhaps by the parent's hWnd).

You don't have to forward messages to the parent, though. I just do usually do that so that most of the dialog's logic is in one place instead of spread out.

EDIT: Corrected statements about creating the child dialogs, window classes etc. I was mixing up dialogs and normal windows, making things more complex than they are in this case. Sorry about that!

Comment: Might be worth adding that I usually only create child dialogs for the contents of tab controls. If I want to programatically generate or repeat the controls in a dialog I would rather have the code create & size the controls at runtime and not use the resource editor at all. However, doing the layout is a pain as you have to look-up all the rules about control sizing and spacing (as there is no API for it).

Comment: I am not sure if I understand: I don't see where I'd have to call `CreateWindow` (and with what registered class). If I recall correctly, the last time I did a Custom Control on a Dialog, the Window was created by the "system", although I had to register a window class.

Comment: @René Apologies, for a dialog you don't need to register a class; you use the system dialog class implicitly and just have to pass a DialogProc directly to CreateDialog ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645434%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ). I was thinking of normal, non-dialog windows. I've edited my answer to correct that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I managed to get it started. In case someone else has the same question: I want also to point out that it helped me to set the "center" flag to false.